# Карта с кластеризацией по ссылке

Tags: яндекс-карты

Есть потребность в публичном размещении карты с тысячами точек. Изначально она фокусируется на Московском регионе. Так как точек много используем кластеризацию. Все это делается сейчас на js api на стороне клиента. Приходится каждый раз заполнять эти тысячи точек, из-за чего клиент страдает.

В конструкторе яндекс карт пробовали импортировать точки через csv, получили js код для вставки. Насколько понимаем конструктор для таких целей не подходит, слишком много объектов. Кластеризация там никак не настраивается.

Можно ли создать вышеописанную карту, с доступом к ней через ссылку (iframe, js код), с настройкой кластеризации? Чтоб на клиенте сразу показалась карта Москвы с несколькими кластерами.

Comment: яндекс карты принципиальны?

Comment: Посмотрите на Loading Object Manager https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/dg/concepts/loading-object-manager/about-docpage/ или на Remote Object Manager https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/dg/concepts/remote-object-manager/about-docpage/

Comment: Да, хотелось бы реализовать на яндекс картах. Если не получится, будем искать альтернативу...

Comment: Loading Object Manager и Remote Object Manager, изучим, спасибо!